# ¿Como evitar que se sobre pase en texto en un dialog?

Tags: primefaces

Buenos dias,

Este es mi codigo:

```
 <p:dialog header="Directorio" widgetVar="dirDialog" modal="true" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" resizable="false">
        <p:outputPanel id="dirDetail" style="text-align:center; width: 150px; height: 150px;">
            <a href="#{busquedaBean1.autor.directorio}" target="_blank" id="txtCopiar">#{busquedaBean1.autor.directorio}</a>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>
```

Imagen del dialog:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que el texto no sobre pase el limite del dialog, es decir que el texto en ves de que se sobre pase, que quede dentro del dialog y si se sobre pasa que se extienda hacia abajo para mostrar el texto completo.

EJEMPLO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO NUEVO**

Estuve investigando un poco y encontre una posible solucion,

Codigo:

```
 <p:dialog header="Directorio" widgetVar="dirDialog" modal="true" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" resizable="false">

        <p:outputPanel id="dirDetail" style="text-align:center;">
            <a href="#{busquedaBean1.autor.directorio}" target="_blank" id="txtCopiar">#{busquedaBean1.autor.directorio}</a>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>
```

el dialog asi como se presenta en el codigo esta auto responsive por lo tanto se ajustara dependiendo de la cantidad de caracteres.

pero algunos computadores tienen zoom en sus navegadores, por lo tanto se ve muy grande y sobre pasa la pantalla.

estuve pensando si en ves de auto ajustarse hacia los lados se auto ajustara hacia abajo.

Comment: me explico bien?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es romper las palabras largas, podrías usar `overflow-wrap: break-word`. Antes Microsoft usaba `word-wrap` para hacer algo similar, pero cuando el resto de navegadores lo incorporaron, le pusieron como nombre `overflow-wrap` ([fuente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap?v=control)).

Con `overflow-wrap` le especificas al navegador cómo debe romper las líneas. Los valores principales: `normal` (las palabras no se rompen, valor por defecto) o `break-word` (si hay una palabra larga, se romperá y una parte aparecerá en una línea y otra parte en la siguiente línea).

Entonces el código quedaría así:

```
<p:dialog header="Directorio" widgetVar="dirDialog" modal="true" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" resizable="false">
    <p:outputPanel id="dirDetail" style="text-align:center; width: 150px; height: 150px;">
        <a href="#{busquedaBean1.autor.directorio}" target="_blank" id="txtCopiar" style="overflow-wrap: break-word">#{busquedaBean1.autor.directorio}</a>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: ya lo intente y nada....

Answer (score 1):

La URL tiene texto sin espacios. Entiendo que ese es el problema con el dialogo que presentas en la primer imagen. Al tag <**a**> agregale el estilo **word-break**.

```
<p:dialog header="Directorio" widgetVar="dirDialog" modal="true" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" resizable="false">
        <p:outputPanel id="dirDetail" style="text-align:center; width: 150px; height: 150px;">
            <a href="#{busquedaBean1.autor.directorio}" 
               target="_blank" 
               id="txtCopiar"
               style="word-break: break-all;">#{busquedaBean1.autor.directorio}</a>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>
```

Comment: no funciono men

Answer (score 0):

ya probaste colocando resizable = true

```html
<p:dialog header="Directorio" widgetVar="dirDialog" modal="true" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" resizable="false">
        <p:outputPanel id="dirDetail" style="text-align:center; width: 150px; height: 150px;">
            <a href="#{busquedaBean1.autor.directorio}" target="_blank" id="txtCopiar">#{busquedaBean1.autor.directorio}</a>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>
```

Comment: no funciona amigo